# Send post with jquery and load a specific selector in a "lightbox"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, lightbox

i want to Post a form value with Jquery $.POST() and load a specific selector i don't know how to do it may be with json or something like that

```
$.post('topic.php', {
    id: id
}, function(data) {
    $("#message")
        .html($(data).('attr', 'title'))
        .hide()
        .slideDown(500); //Fade in the data given by the topic.php file
});
return false;
});​
```

i just want to load the title and description not the whole page

i want to retrieve this title and description in a lightbox how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, jQuery (and even many browsers internally) sends a HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header. You could catch it in topic.php and returns json instead of html. Check this link for an how-to: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/how-to-tell-ajax-request-php/

If you really want to extract content from returned html, it's fairly simple: create a blank DOM object with jQuery, give it the HTML data, then retrieve whatever element you want with the find function:

```
$.post('topic.php', {
    id: id
}, function(data) {
$("#message")
    .html($('<div></div>').html(data).find('a').('attr', 'title'))
    .hide()
    .slideDown(500); //Fade in the data given by the topic.php file
});
return false;
});​
```

Replace the 'a' tag in find function by any selector you need. A working example here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GeX7d/

**EDIT**: for the lightbox part, there are plenty of tutorials on the web that describe the process, this one will fit your needs: http://www.cssjockey.com/web-design-tutorials/an-easy-way-to-create-light-box-with-jquery-css

Comment: and what about the lightbox?

Comment: What to you mean for light box? IS it a little message box at the top right corner ? Then just create a div with jQuery, and append the div to the body, I updated the fiddle with an example: [http://jsfiddle.net/GeX7d/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/GeX7d/1/). If you need more, you have plenty tutorials, here is one for example that will work well for you: [http://www.cssjockey.com/web-design-tutorials/an-easy-way-to-create-light-box-with-jquery-css](http://www.cssjockey.com/web-design-tutorials/an-easy-way-to-create-light-box-with-jquery-css)

Comment: no i mean a window that opens like facebook when you want to share something

Comment: yep, i edited my comment with a link to a tutorial, This part of your question is too large for Stack Overflow. Hope it helps.